Facing installation issue on installing cuda toolkit 12.4.1 in ubuntu under proxmox environment
I am trying to install cuda toolkit 12.4.1 in ubuntu under proxmoxlogs of nvidia installer environment from past week but have been facing the same issue( please check the nvidia installer logs) when running the runfile ( local.run ). Any help would be much appreciated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Actually I am not able to run local file. run of cuda toolkit in linux environment and I have also attached the error image named above as logs of nvidia installer.

We currently don't know what Ubuntu product/release you are asking about; thus our information is somewhat limited. I noted a 6.5 kernel, but no details as to if you're using a HWE kernel stack on a LTS release, or using the native 6.5 kernel for a non-LTS release. The more details you provide, the more likely we're able to provide some advice (or better an answer).
